# Factorial inverse equation

Tags: factorial, poisson-distribution

I need to find a solution to a problem and I need to solve an equation. The following equation is the result of some manipulation.

I'm a little bit rusty and I can't see how to find a simple solution ( to be honest I can't find a solution at all ):

$e^{-A} \cdot A^x = x! \cdot K$

What I need is $x$. $A$ and $K$ are real, positive constant numbers an I'm expecting the solution would be real and positive. Does anyone has suggestions ?

Comment: So... are we using the Gamma function?  Since it is very unlikely that $x$ is an integer...

Comment: Note that if we restrict $x>0$, it is plenty likely that there may be no such solutions.

Comment: Well, to be honest i don't know what the Gamma function is, but to be precise $x$ is a natural ( integer $>= 0$ ), because it rapresent the number of defect in an wafer of silicon. So it's reasonable to think to it as an integer bigger than zero. Does it help ?

Comment: It makes it almost certain that there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to solve this equation, I think it is better to get a sense of the possible solutions. Maybe this graph could help:

[image: graph]

As you see, the solution is not unique for some values of $A$ and $K$, while it doesn't have any solution for some positive values of $A$ and $K$.

Comment: Looking this I got an idea. I can plot the function $e^{-A} \cdot A^y = x! \cdot K$ and then plot the equation $x = y$. The solution is in the cross. The only problem is to find the values a reasonable range for $x$ and $y$ .

Comment: @haster8558 Why not just plot the function $e^{-A} \cdot A^x - x! \cdot K$ and then find its roots?

Comment: Ah right. I was in rush. It's definitely better. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

$x!$ is not defined for arbitrary real positive $x$, just for nonnegative integers.  You could replace it by $\Gamma(x+1)$.  But still your equation can't be solved in "closed form".  Numerical methods might be tried.

Comment: Ok, so it isn't possible to get a solution in closed form but it has some solutions. Any idea how to find a numerical solution ? Any algorithm simple to implement ?

Comment: Newton's method should work.  It might be better to work with the logarithms of both sides of the equation, to avoid numerical overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution - not sure if it will be of particularly good numerical stability. Take logs:

$$ \ln{(e^{-A} A^x)} = \ln{(x! K)} \implies - A + x \ln{A} = \ln{x!} + \ln{K}.$$

You might be able to solve this numerically if you use a an accurate enough approximation for $\ln x!,$ using the Stirling series:

$$ \ln x! \approx x \ln x - x + \frac{1}{2} \ln{2\pi x} + \frac{1}{12 x} - \frac{1}{360 x^3} + \dots$$

so a solution will be close to the solution of, say,

$$ x \ln x - (1 + \ln A)x+\frac{1}{2} \ln{2\pi x} + (A + \ln K) = 0.$$